# Measure size of ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a ViewGroup that contain one child(ImageButton).
I want the viewGroup has exact size of its child.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int desiredWidth = getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth();
        int desiredHeight = getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight();

        int width = resolveSize(desiredWidth,widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = resolveSize(desiredHeight,heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(width,height);
    }
```

I get children size (ImageButton) by getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredWidth() but they return 0 value.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not measure the child view, hence its width and height are not set (yet).

Either call `super.onMeasure(...)` in your method to let your super class measure the child, or do it yourself by calling `child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)`.